# why c style array in class without user-defined operator= support deep copy

Tags: c++, c++11

when reading the source code of [std::array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/api/a00981_source.html)

it is something like:

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct array
{
     T c_arr[N];
};
```

I am wondering why in this case the automatic generated operator= support deep copy?

```
std:：array<int, 3> a1{1, 2, 3}, a2;
a2 = a1;

//all the elements in a1.c_arr have been copied to a2.c_arr
copy(begin(a2), end(a2), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\t"));

output:
1 2 3
```

If we define a class which has no user-defined operator=, it also support deep copy.

```
struct Test
{
    int a[3];
};

Test a1{1, 2, 3}, a2;
a2 = a1;

//all the elements in a1.a have been copied to a2.a
copy(begin(a2), end(a2), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\t"));


output:
1 2 3
```

Comment: In what sense is that a "deep copy"? The array is contained within the structure.

Comment: All the element in the array a1 is copied to array a2, in order to copy an array, we normally need a loop, right?

Comment: Assigning a `struct` just copies the entire contents of the object. There may or may not be a loop in the generated code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because wrong question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` on an instance of a `std::array` return the beginning and the ending iterator of the actual array inside the `std::array`.

I don't see why a copy-constructor has anything to do with this. I see no copy-construction taking place anywhere, here.

Comment: All the elements in a1.c_arr have been copied to a2.c_arr. But if we want to copy an array, we need a loop.

Comment: That's an assignment operator, not copy-construction.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how it works. It's the only behavior that can possible make sense, except for doing nothing or being a compiler error.

A C-style array is an aggregate consisting of multiple instances of the element type — in particular, it is *not* a pointer type.